# Lower-bound Runtime of this pseudo-code

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory, time-complexity, big-o

```
for i = 0 to n do
for j = n to 0 do
for k = 1 to j-i do
print (k)
```

I'm wondering about the lower-bound runtime of the above code. In the notes I am reading it explains the lower bound runtime to be

[image]

with the explanation;

To find the lower bound on the running time, consider the values of i, such that 0 <= i <= n/4 and values of j, such that 3n/4 <= j <= n. Note that for each of the n^2/16 different combinations of i and j, the innermost loop executes at least n/2 times.

Can someone explain where these numbers came from? They seem to be arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are `n` iterations of the first loop and for each of them `n` iterations of the second loop. In total these are `n^2` iterations of the second loop.

Now if you only consider the lower quarter of possible values for `i`, then you have `n^2/4` iterations of the inner loop left. If you also only consider the upper quarter of values for `j` then you have `n^2/16` iterations of the inner loop left.

For each iteration of these constrained cases you have `j-i >= 3n/4-n/4 = n/2` and therefore the most inner loop is iterated at least `n/2` times for each of these `n^2/16` iterations of the outer loops. Therefore the full number of iterations of the most inner loop is at least `n^2/16*n/2`.

Because we considered only specific iterations, the actual number of iterations is higher and this result is a lower bound. Therefore the algorithm is in `Omega(n^3)`.

The values are insofar arbitrary that you could use many others. But these are some simple ones which make the argument `j-i >= 3n/4-n/4 = n/2` possible. For example if you took only the lower half of the `i` iterations and the upper half of the `j` iterations, then you would have `j-i >= n/2-n/2 = 0`, leading to `Omega(0)`, which is not interesting. If you took something like lower tenth and upper tenth it would still work, but the numbers wouldn't be as nice.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really explain the ranges from your book, but if you attempt to proceed via the methodology below, I hope it would become more clear to find what is it that you are looking for.

The ideal way for the outer loop (index **i**) and the inner loop (index **j**) is as follows, since `j - i >= 1` should be sustained, so that the innermost loop would execute (at least once in every case).

The performed decomposition was made because the range of `j from i to 0` is ignored by the innermost loop.

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ ) {
    for ( j = n; j > i ; j -- ) {
        for ( k = 1;  k <= j - i ; k ++ ) {
            printf(k);
        }
    }
}
```

This algorithm's order of growth complexity `T(n)` is:

[image]

Hence, your algorithm does iterate more than the algorithm above (`j goes from n to 0`).

Using Sigma Notation, you can do this:

[image]
[image]

Where `c` represent the execution cost of `print(k)`, and `c'` is the execution cost of the occurring iterations that don't involve the innermost loop.